# Copy data from table to table doing INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to copy a lot of data from one table to another. If the data already exists, I need to update it, otherwise I need to insert it. The data to be copied is selecting using a WHERE condition. The data has a primary key (a string of up to 12 characters).

If I was just inserting the data, I would do

```
INSERT INTO T2 SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM T1 WHERE T1.ID ='I'
```

but I cannot figure out how to do the INSERT / UPDATE. I keep seeing references to upserts and MERGE, but MERGE appears to have issues,and I cannot figure ut how to do the upsert for multiple records.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Do the tables have primary keys? If yes, then this should be easy barring any need for real optimization.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid merges (though you should not be afraid of it) you can do something like

```
update t2
  set col1 = t1.col1
      ,col2 = t1.col2
from t2 
join t1
   on t2.[joinkey] = t1.[joinkey]
where [where clause]
```

And after for the ones that you do not have

```
insert into t2(col1,col2)
select col1,col2 from t1
where not exists (select * from t2 where t1.[joinkey] = t2.[joinkey])
```

in such way you first update the ones that match and then insert the ones that do not. Also if you want it in one go you can wrap it in a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

It is commonly known as `UPSERT` operation. Yes you are correct in saying merge has some issues with it so stay away from it.

A simple approach assuming there is a Primary Key column in Both tables called `PK_Col` would be something like this...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

 -- Update already existing records
   UPDATE T2 
     SET T2.Col1 = T1.Col1
        ,T2.Col2 = T1.Col2
   FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.PK_COl = T1.PK_Col 

-- Insert missing records 
  INSERT INTO T2 (COL1, COL2 )
  SELECT COL1, COL2 
  FROM T1 
  WHERE T1.ID ='I'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM T2 
                  WHERE T2.PK_COl = T1.PK_Col )

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Wrap the whole `UPSERT` operation in one transaction.

Comment: Shouldn't the UPDATE statement also have a `WHERE` condition?

Comment: The update statement is joining on the primary key column , it would update anything if there isn't a corresponding row, again it is only for demo purpose you can add conditions as many as you want , this is not a full solution but a demo to put you in the right direction.

Comment: OK, I was just a trifle confused because the `INSERT` had a check on the ID column.

Comment: @SimonCallan oh no I have added this check in insert since you had it in your question, I don't know why its there :) since I don't know the exact login here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF EXISTS` something like:

```
if exists (select * from table with (updlock,serializable) where key = @key)
begin
   update table set ...
   where key = @key
end
else
begin
   insert table (key, ...)
   values (@key, ...)
end
```

Another solution is to check `@@ROWCOUNT`

```
UPDATE MyTable SET FieldA=@FieldA WHERE Key=@Key

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   INSERT INTO MyTable (FieldA) VALUES (@FieldA)
```